# Jquery detect event

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using jquery password generator plugin. But I also want to show the strength meter, after the password generated it is pasted into the textbox. I want to call a function when the password is pasted into the text-box,but I cant detect the event.

I tried :-

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://gigstarr.com/js/pGenerator.jquery.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

    $('#mylink').pGenerator({
        'bind': 'click',
        'passwordElement': '#user_password',
        'displayElement': '#user_password_show',
        'passwordLength': 16,
        'uppercase': true,
        'lowercase': true,
        'numbers':   true,
        'specialChars': true,
        'onPasswordGenerated': function(generatedPassword) {
            alert('Please copy your Password :-' + generatedPassword);
        }
    });

});
</script>
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Try: `'bind': 'click paste',`

Comment: have you checked if there is any error in firebug console ?

Comment: _"After the password generatd it is pasted into the textbox."_ - What? How? From the alert in your code it appears that you expect the user to manually copy/paste the password between fields on your page, is that right? That seems a strange kind of user experience.

Comment: You can check here http://gigstarr.com/signup

Answer (score 2):

I think your looking for the `change` event

Comment: You can check here gigstarr.com/signup